# Как вывести модальное окно при наведении мыши в левую / правую часть браузера?

Tags: javascript

Как написать функцию, которая выводит модальное окно при наведении мыши в левую / правую часть окна браузера?

```
function showModule(e) {
    if (e.pageX > 0 && e.pageX <= 20 && e.pageY > 0 && e.pageY < 2000) {
        alert('Месседж');
    }
}

document.onmousemove = showModule(e);
```

Эта чертовщина не работает, но нужно что-то подобное.

Comment: `document.onmousemove = showModule;`

Comment: Премного благодарен! Такая пустячная ошибка)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function showModule (e) {
       if (e.clientX < 100 && e.clientX > 0 && e.clientY>0 && e.clientY < 300) {
                alert('Module');
}
}

document.onmousemove = showModule;
```

Этот вариант более удобен, чем с использованием pageX, так как этот ввриант относительно окна, а не страницы)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function showModule(e) {
    var w = window.innerWidth
      || document.documentElement.clientWidth
      || document.body.clientWidth;
    if (e.pageX <= 20 || (e.pageX >= w - 20)) {
        alert('Месседж');
    }
}

document.onmousemove = showModule;
```